# Use of Function in For loop in c programming

Tags: for-loop

Can we make use of function in for loop in c programming language like the below example...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (foo(); i == 1; i = 2)
        printf("In for loop\n");
        printf("After loop\n");
}
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Also please explain the output of this code ....Answer --->After loop.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, so it will return 1 and the loop will never be executed. the loop will be executed if i==1 but i is still 0. This will mean the statement printf("In for loop\n"); is not executed and it will continue after this loop ->  printf("After loop\n");
for better understanding you could use brackets surrounding the for loop and indentation.without brackets the for loop includes just the next statement:

```
    for (foo(); i == 1; i = 2){
        printf("In for loop\n");
    }
    printf("After loop\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using for loops does not make a whole lot of sense.
The place where you are calling foo() is where the loop variable usually gets initialized.
Think about the general concepts of for loops:

```
for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT)
```

It would make more sense to write

```
for (i = foo(); i == 1; i = 2)
```

I see another problem with your for loop in the AFTERTHOUGHT part.
You usually want to modify the loop variable there, but in a way that it depends on the previous state. In the most simple case just increment it, thus write:

```
for (i = foo(); i == 1; i++)
```

Then look at the CONDITION part. It should be true for a range of values, otherwise the loop will terminate quickly (after one iteration in this case). You would maybe want to write something like

```
for (i = foo(); i <= 3; i++)
```

to have 3 iterations.

You get the basic idea?

Comment: Yes i know the basic concepts of look i simply asked about the use of function in for() loop and explanation of output......But thanks you very much for your of basic working of for loop...........